# Deploy Rails application in Docker and kubernetes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, kubernetes

I have rails application which I need to deploy in docker and kubernetes from my local Mac machine(Mac high Sierra version 10.13.6).How to configure docker and kubernetes in Mac.

I couldn't find docker installable for Mac high Sierra version 10.13.6.

I am using below servers in my application.

```
1.redis
2.sidekiq
3.puma server
4.postgresql(for Prod)/sqlite(for Dev) DB
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on  [this git hub issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4996#issuecomment-709841890) , docker for mac is maintained for only current and previous two versions of mac.

Try to install docker for mac 2.3.5.0 version or upgrade to latest mac.[Here](https://desktop.docker.com/mac/stable/48029/Docker.dmg) is the link for 2.3.0.5 version of docker for mac.

After installing docker, you can run your own docker images and other official images of redis,postgresql..etc.